# ThreadPoolExecutor throws RejectedExecutionException after shutting down

Tags: android, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have two buttons for start download and stop download. I used the `ThreadPoolExecutor` for multiple downloads. I shut down the `ThreadPoolExecutor` when the stop button is clicked. And I start execution again on `ThreadPoolExecutor` when the start button is clicked. I got `RejectedExecutionException`. 
I would like to know that how to re-execute the `ThreadPoolExecutor` that has already shutdown.

**EDIT:**
error stack.

```
11-18 10:41:52.929: E/AndroidRuntime(27351): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-18 10:41:52.929: E/AndroidRuntime(27351): java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.task.SyncTask@42614978 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@414ce138[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 181]
11-18 10:41:52.929: E/AndroidRuntime(27351):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1979)
11-18 10:41:52.929: E/AndroidRuntime(27351):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:786)
11-18 10:41:52.929: E/AndroidRuntime(27351):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1307)
11-18 10:41:52.929: E/AndroidRuntime(27351):    at com.MainActivity$2.handleMessage(MainActivity.java:394)
11-18 10:41:52.929: E/AndroidRuntime(27351):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-18 10:41:52.929: E/AndroidRuntime(27351):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
11-18 10:41:52.929: E/AndroidRuntime(27351):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5092)
11-18 10:41:52.929: E/AndroidRuntime(27351):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-18 10:41:52.929: E/AndroidRuntime(27351):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-18 10:41:52.929: E/AndroidRuntime(27351):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
11-18 10:41:52.929: E/AndroidRuntime(27351):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
11-18 10:41:52.929: E/AndroidRuntime(27351):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdown%28%29), after calling shutdown "no new tasks will be accepted".

You shouldn't need to explicitly shutdown the executor (it'll take care of that itself once all the threads in it are done).

Is there a message in the RejectedExecutionException you're getting?

Comment: I need to stop all queue threads if the stop button is clicked.

Comment: Could call interrupt() on the threads... or do what you're doing now and create a new ThreadPoolExecutor when you want to start up new ones.

Comment: yeah I think creating new one is the better.